# Find index of element from IQueryable

Tags: c#, sitecore, iqueryable

Hi I am trying to find the position of specific element from IQueryable. I dont want to covert to list then search for it because the process is heavy if the number of element is huge.

I tried .TakeWhile(x => x.ItemId.Equals(ItemId)) but it show me function not supported.
Below is how I doing it now using loop through the query. Is there any better approach for it?

```
IQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem> contextQueryable = context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem>().Where(query);
if (ItemId != ID.Null)
{
 int i = 0;
 foreach (var x in contextQueryable)
 {                            
  if(x.ItemId.Equals(ItemId))
  {
   Position = i;
   break;
  }
  i++;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```cs
var contextQueryable = context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem>().Where(query).GetResults();
var result = contextQueryable.Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
   .FirstOrDefault(itemWithIndex => itemWithIndex.Item.Document.ItemId.Guid == ItemId);

if (result != null)
  index = result.Index;
```

Comment: Edited the answer: added GetResults and change the equals. Note that ItemId is a Guid now. This should work (is tested).